# CSS Display: inline-block but Stack Divs only if they overlap

Tags: html, css, display

I have the following divs below:

```css
.parent {
  padding: 10px;
  background: grey;
}

.child {
  background: green;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
}

.stacked {
  left: 0px;
}

.three {
  left: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child stacked">div1</div>
  <div class="child stacked">div2</div>
  <div class="child three">div3</div>
</div>
```

This looks like the following:
[image]

I would like divs 1 and 2 to stack as they do, but since div3 does not collide with the divs above, I'd like it to vertically aline with div 1.

If I switch display to inline or inline-block, it pushes div 2 to the right of div one. and the left values are not accurate to the parant.
[image]

The left values of the divs will be dynamically generated so I cannot know if the divs are overlapping or not.

Is this possible?

Comment: Could you be a little more specific what the end goal is here? How many items do need to be accounted for?

Comment: Will 3 always have left offset of 200px? will all child elements always have a width of 50px?

Comment: The divs are calendar events, and the parent is a timeline of a day. So there can be any number of events (child divs) and the left value of the divs needs to be accurate to the day (parent) since its position shows the time.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: If you really want to align the 3rd `div` using positioning, then you can do it like so:

```css
.parent {
  padding: 10px;
  background: grey;
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  background: green;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
}

.stacked {
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
}

.three {
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child stacked">div1</div>
  <div class="child stacked">div2</div>
  <div class="child three">div3</div>
</div>
```

You can use the [column-count](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_column-count.asp) property like so:

```css
.parent {
  padding: 10px;
  background: grey;
  column-count: 2;
}

.child {
  background: green;
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">div1</div>
  <div class="child">div2</div>
  <div class="child">div3</div>
</div>
```

Or you can use `flexbox` to wrap vertically, like so:

```css
.parent {
  padding: 10px;
  background: grey;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 50px;
}

.child {
  background: green;
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">div1</div>
  <div class="child">div2</div>
  <div class="child">div3</div>
</div>
```

Here's using `grid`:

```css
.parent {
  padding: 10px;
  background: grey;
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
}

.child {
  background: green;
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">div1</div>
  <div class="child">div2</div>
  <div class="child">div3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: this sort of works but now div 3s left value is not accurate to the parent.

Comment: What do you mean by, *"The left values of the divs will be dynamically generated so I cannot know if the divs are overlapping or not."*?

Comment: The divs will align to the parent based on time. Like a horizontal calendar. So the left value of the children needs to be accurate. So 2 divs may overlap but some will not.

Comment: Then use absolute positioning on it, like this it will stay relative to the parent.

Comment: as @prettyInPink said, adding absolute positioning to the children will make it relative to the nearest positioned ancestor/parent.

Comment: @ChrisScott edited the snippet.

Comment: This will work but if a 4th div is mapped into the parent that overlaps the horizontal space with div 3, then div 4 won't be pushed lower.

Comment: doesn't the 3 alternative solutions fix that though? if you use any of the three then you wouldn't worry about any positioning to achieve the result you want no?

Comment: @ChrisScott I believe you should be more clear about the desired outcome, you're unnecessarily confusing everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :
wrap div3 item in another div and give it a class property of flex-container.

```
.flex-container {
  align-content: flex-start;
}
```

Ensure the flex direction is horizontal.